# Rails 3-2. Multiple file uploading. Ruby issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

I am using Carrierwave for file uploading and have got the following form, which allows me to submit several files:

```
<%= form_tag load_patterns_contacts_path, multipart: true, multiple: true do %>
  <%= file_field_tag 'qqfile[]', id: "upload_pattern", multiple: true %>
  <%= submit_tag "Load", id: "save_pattern", :class => 'btn btn-primary btn-success', multiple: true%>
<% end %>
```

Here is the code in my controller, which load submited files to the server:

```
 @uploader = EmailPatternsUploader.new

  params[:qqfile].each do |p|
    tempfile = open(p.original_filename)
      puts tempfile
    @uploader.store!(tempfile)
  end

  redirect_to contacts_path
  flash[:success] = "Uploaded successfully."
```

It works fine, if filename looks like "text.xlsx", "image.jpg" etc. But if it is contains special symbols like "_partial.html.erb" then I have got Errno:ENOENT (No such file or directory - _partial.html.erb)

I have tried to add

```
CarrierWave::SanitizedFile.sanitize_regexp = /[^[:word:]\.\_\-\+]/
```

in my carrierwave.rb initializer, but it gives no result.

Thanks in advance for help!

UPDATE:

I have understood, that the problem not in special symbol "_", but in the fact, that samples I am  trying to upload contains two dots ("."). I think I need to modify regular expression in order to avoid two dots

UPDATE:

I am sorry for the last comments. I have understood, that the matter not in special symbols at all and not in a name of file. The problem that **i can upload files only from {Rails.root} path**. If I choose another directory, I have got aforementioned error and cannot upload a file. How can I configure Carrierwave path directory?

Comment: checked the expression on [rubular](http://rubular.com/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally find an answer on my question.

The error was in these strings of code:

```
params[:qqfile].each do |p|
  tempfile = open(p.original_filename)
    puts tempfile
  @uploader.store!(tempfile)
end
```

I have understood, that I need to pass an object [ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/UploadedFile.html) in Carrierwave store! method. Thats why the mentioned above code shall be the following:

```
params[:qqfile].each do |p|
  puts p.original_filename
    puts p
  @uploader.store!(p)
end
```

==================================================================================

Hope someone find this solution for multiple file uploading with Carrierwave and without JQuery useful.

1) Create an uploader, using Carrierwave.

```
    rails g uploader EmailPatterns
```

2) Create a custom action for your controller (watch [Railscast#35](http://railscasts.com/episodes/35-custom-rest-actions) and [Railscast#38](http://railscasts.com/episodes/38-multibutton-form) to make it clear) and put there something like this (load_patterns in my case):

```
    def load_patterns
      @uploader = EmailPatternsUploader.new
        params[:qqfile].each {|p| @uploader.store!(p)}
      redirect_to contacts_path
      flash[:success] = "Uploaded successfully"
    end
```

To make it work you need to specify custom route(config/routes.rb) for your action:

```
  resources :contacts do
    collection { post :load_patterns}
  end
```

and to create a form, where you will get params with your uploading files (see p.3)

3) Create form, where you need to specify the option multiple:true in order to allow user to select several files to load (param name with [ ] is a necessary requirement, because we are loading several files) :

```
    <%= form_tag load_patterns_contacts_path, multipart: true, multiple: true do %>
       <%= file_field_tag 'qqfile[]', id: "upload_pattern", multiple: true %>
       <%= submit_tag "Load",  id: "save_pattern", :class => 'btn btn-primary btn-success', multiple: true%>
    <% end %>
```

Then your custom action will work.